# how to delete the current screen from history stack in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

In `react-router-dom v6` we can call `navigate(-1)` in order to go one screen back. but what I want to achieve is a kind of `navigate(-1)` which removes the current URL from the stack as well.
So the purpose is to have a disabled `forward` button in the browser after the user has gone one screen back.
like:

[image: disabled back button]

Note that I also tried replacing the current URL with the previous one but it's not a good solution because if the user clicks on the back button they will remain on the same screen which is weird.

Comment: can you try this? `navigate(-1, { replace: true })` I am not sure if it will work, but from the docs `replace` as `true` will update the stack as per your requirements

Comment: @PranayNailwal no it doesn't work. I already tried it

Comment: @PranayNailwal Reread the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate), the `navigate` function takes  either a `to` object and `options` arguments ***OR*** a `delta` number.

Comment: Using a delta navigation will only navigate forward or backward through the existing history stack, it doesn't mutate the stack. `navigate("..", { replace: true })` is about as close as you'll get with RRDv6 APIs, but note that this isn't a back POP navigation, it's a redirect (*REPLACE*) one path segment up. In other words if user is on `"/test"` and navigates to `"/foo/bar"`, `navigate("..", { replace: true })` will take them to `"/foo"` which isn't what you are expecting at all. The solution you seek likely involves creating a custom router to use a custom history object.

Comment: What is the point of having a forward navigation button in the UI if you just want to remove any "forward history" and disable it? This seems to deviate from the expected browser forward/back navigation button behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to modify the history, and As far as I know, there's no way to delete a history entry (or state).

One way I've been looking into is to handle the history yourself in JavaScript with `onpopState` listener

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#examples

Comment: what do you mean with handle? none of the methods on `history` can solve my problem!

Comment: @RezaShoja I mean creating a custom history object.